# How to hide or delete terminated containers, services or stacks?

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

Is there a way to stop displaying the terminated containers, services or stacks in either the web UI or on the CLI? It's starting to become cluttered and difficult to isolate what I'm working on amongst the terminated test containers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They disappear within a few minutes from both the CLI and the Web UI. After I asked this question, I went back and run...

```
docker-cloud container ps
```

and they had all gone.